# How to set ipython/jupyter as the default python terminal for vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython, jupyter

How can I choose ipython/jupyter as the DEFAULT python terminal? I use both a windows 10 and a linux machine with the anaconda distribution.

If I type "ipython" on the terminal, it opens an ipython session. If I run the debugger or shift+enter a line, it automatically runs on a "barebones" python shell. Should be simple...but I have been googling and messing with the settings for half an hour with no success.

Looked up

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask

[Use IPython REPL in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310689/use-ipython-repl-in-vs-code/52324509#52324509)

but could not find a way to set it up on my linux or win10 machines. Any ideas?

Comment: i don't know if this is what you want but it you have the Jupyter Extension loaded then make the 1st line of your code  #%%. Then  if you do this an option appears in your you code  that says "run cell". Clicking this runs you code in the code editor.  This is like a default option because all python codes with #%% in the first line.has that option directly from the code editor.  I posted this as a comment because i don't know if this is related to your question.

Comment: That is a useful trick, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A slightly neater way to achieve @TwoUnderscorez's answer is to just launch the module with `-m IPython`:

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": [
   "-m",
   "IPython"
]
```

**Edit:** For anyone struggling with `IndentationError: unexpected indent` errors, try the following:

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": [
   "-m",
   "IPython",
   "--no-autoindent",
]
```

(wouldn't have just added a comment to the existing answer, but not enough rep)

Comment: Thanks for the "--no-autoindent" trick! Saved me a lot of pain!

Comment: Hi, it works great thanks, but everytime I need to click in terminal and hit enter to run code. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, here is my response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332723/how-can-i-force-shiftenter-to-run-selection-and-execute-it-immediately-running/61700005#61700005

Comment: You are a life saver. The trick "--no-autoindent" saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

1. In your VSCode, press **ctrl+shift+P**, start typing **settings** and click on **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**
2. Add this key-value pair to tell python to start ipython:

   ```
   "python.terminal.launchArgs": [
       "-c",
       "\"from IPython import start_ipython; start_ipython()\""
   ]
   ```

Comment: Currently this seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

There currently isn't support to specify an alternative REPL that isn't the Python interpreter you use to execute code. One trick some people do if you want this just for sending code to the REPL is they launch the REPL once, exit it, and then launch `ipython` manually as the extension will continue to use that terminal instance for future code sent to the REPL.

Comment: Oh ok, I hope a built-in way of changing the REPL comes with updates. Yes, that workaround solves most of the problem.

Comment: We have some plans for something around interactive coding, but I can't say more than that ;) .

Comment: Just for future reference, I am having an issue with this workaround on linux machines. When I try to select and run (shift+enter) multiple lines of code it runs only the first line. I find myself using the jupyternotebook more and more because of these limitations. It is an odd workflow.

Comment: @BrettCannon any update on this? For beginners it would be really nice if they could run code in IPython, but telling them to go and edit their settings is a pretty hard task if you are just starting out to learn Python. I think this should be the default setting if IPython is installed.

Comment: @cbrnr no update, but please feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python (I would offer to do it for you, but I'm on vacation and I would have to log into my work account to open the issue).