# How can i force SHIFT+ENTER to run selection and execute it immediately running ipython in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I have added the setting below in vscode to launch ipython when i used shift+enter to run selection.

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": [
    "-c",
    "\"from IPython import start_ipython; start_ipython()\""
]
```

Now when i run a selection, the code will not execute in the terminal immediately, i need to navigate to the terminal and hit enter until it does. 
This problem doesn't occur if i just use the basic python terminal to execute single lines.

Is there a setting to fix this so the snippet runs immediately in the terminal? I've searched preferences and can't find anything.

```
print("Hello World")

In [1]: print("Hello World")
   ...:
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make some workaround.

You need to install extension `multi-command`.

Add this code in `settings.json`

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.executeIPython",
        "interval": 40,
        "sequence": [
            "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
            "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToBottom",
            {"command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": { "text": "\u000D" }},
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    },
]
```

And then you can use this command as shortcut (add to `keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "multiCommand.executeIPython",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !python.datascience.ownsSelection && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'" 
  }
```

Unfortunately for the first time (when ipython console is not opened) you need to hit enter. But later it works as it should.

Edit: With `interval` param it works better. Thanks to: [DEVNULLDNE answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17172)

Comment: Works very well! Thank you very much!