# Run selection using IPython in VSCode active terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm thinking about moving from spyder to vscode. Mostly data mining work. 
To me, spyder is good, but without so many extensions as in vscode.

However, I really don't like the Python:interactive window (with jupyter). It's too slow, not having autocomplete function, using more RAM, and showing results not as compact as I want, and sometimes get stuck when the output is huge.

I really like testing code pieces in Ipython in spyder. Ipython is also possible in vscode. However, the function is not good enough.

(1) I have made the "run selection/line in python terminal" automatically run with IPython. But when I opened an Python/IPython terminal first, then use the run selection function, **it always runs it in a new terminal**, not in the active one I opened.

(2) When I click the run selection or its shortcut, it sends my selected code into the terminal window successfully, **without running it**! I always need to press one more enter for it. This is kind of so silly.

So, can I solve them by just adding something in the json settings?

Comment: "the active one I opened" do you mean in vscode or another terminal emulator ?

Comment: of course in vscode

Comment: Thank you for the precision. I edited your post to make it more clear, especially the title, so that I hope it's easier to grasp by others.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a repro for the Python:Interactive window getting stuck would you? I work on the Interactive window and we'd love to fix the problem.

Comment: Try my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332723/how-can-i-force-shiftenter-to-run-selection-and-execute-it-immediately-running/61700005#61700005

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I have recently switched to vscode and I have been having the same problem. I found a workaround for the "extra" enter press necessary to run the selection on Ipython.

This solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61444964/10652754) answer.

**1. Install [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.macros) extension**

**2. In settings.json**

```
"macros.list": {
   "execSelectiioninTerminal": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        {"command": "$delay","args": {"delay": 100}},
        {"command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence","args": { "text": "\n" }},
    ],
}
```

**3. In keybinding.json:**

```
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "macros.execSelectiioninTerminal",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
}
```