# Set IPython terminal as default in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've installed most popular Python extensions in vscode. So I can do `shift+enter` to execute some selected code into a *python terminal*.

This uses `/usr/bin/python3` as default. I would like to use IPython3 instead. However, I don't find such settings in `settings.json`.

How can I configure the default Python terminal in vscode?

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Comment: Here is my answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332723/how-can-i-force-shiftenter-to-run-selection-and-execute-it-immediately-running/61700005#61700005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The reason for "I can do shift+enter to execute some selected code into a python terminal." is that "`shift`+`enter`" is the default shortcut key of VSCode, and the command it executes is "`python.execSelectionInTerminal`":

```
{ "key": "shift+enter",           "command": "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'" },
```

2.Set the default terminal to ipython in VSCode, please use "`ipython.exe`" to execute the file in `settings.json`: for example:

> ```
> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts\\ipython.exe",
> ```

Use:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open a file with the suffix .ipynb and vs code will do the rest

Comment: I do not want to use Jupyter !