# Sending code snippets to the debug console interpreter

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'd like to send code I have selected from the editor to the interpreter running in the debugging console during an active debugging session. Can I do this in VSCode? If so, how?

#### Update 1

While Mark (accepted answer) provided what seems to be the right command (it works for me from the contextual menu with the mouse), this isn't working for me yet as a keyboard binding, and I reported this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95395).

#### Update 2

This started working again as of April 21, 2020 (latest Insiders version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_run-selectionline-in-terminal-repl

> **Run Selection/Line in Terminal (REPL)**
>
> The `Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal` command
>   (Shift+Enter) is a simple way to take whatever code is selected, or
>   the code on the current line if there is no selection, and run it in
>   the Python Terminal. An identical `Run Selection/Line in Python
>   Terminal` command is also available on the context menu for a selection
>   in the editor.
>
> VS Code automatically removes indents based on the first non-empty
>   line of the selection, shifting all other lines left accordingly.
>
> Source code that runs in the terminal/REPL is cumulative until the
>   current instance of the terminal is closed.
>
> The command opens the Python Terminal if necessary; you can also open
>   the interactive REPL environment directly using the `Python: Start REPL`
>   command. (Initial startup might take a few moments especially if the
>   first statement you run is an import.)
>
> On first use of the `Python: Run Selection/Line` in Python Terminal
>   command, VS Code may send the text to the REPL before that environment
>   is ready, in which case the selection or line is not run. If you
>   encounter this behavior, try the command again when the REPL has
>   finished loading.

And see [Use IPython REPL in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310689/use-ipython-repl-in-vs-code) for info about the IPython REPL.

---

---------  generic info for other languages   -------------------------------------------------------------

It sounds like you want to send it the repl.  There is an unbound command:

`editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl`

which will send selected text to the debug repl.

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",           // whatever you want here
  "command": "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl"
},
```

Comment: Weird, this isn't working for me (in the latest version of Insiders), and I see no error or message anywhere. I guess I'll file a ticket

Comment: It works for me but I don't use python so I can't test it there.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is indeed the correct answer even if it doesn't quite work for me (I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95395) w/ them in case others run into a similar problem)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot send a selection of code to the debugger. You need to debug the whole file or use the Interactive Window support to debug a specific cell.

Comment: Thanks Brett - Do you know if that's a design choice? If so, are you aware of any threads where that idea was discussed / discarded, or where the basis for ruling out this feature was stablished? Or do you think that's more of a limitation of the way these two entities (debugger console process and editor) can communicate today?

Comment: Also, I'd be interested in knowing how you would reconcile what you wrote here with the `commandID` that @mark posted in another answer.

Comment: Mark's answer is different because he was aware of a VS Code-specific command that I wasn't. I was speaking from the perspective of the Python extension where there isn't specific support for this.

Comment: Got it - Thanks @Brett

Comment: BTW I was coincidentally just now opening [a related feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11308) on this topic (FYI if you are interested). Thanks again.