# Possible to get pycharm-style "run with Python Console" functionality in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

In PyCharm, there's a handy button next to `if __name__...` statements that runs a script,

[image]

with configurations for the run in a run configurations menu.

One of the options is to "Run with Python Console":

[image]

This is really handy, because I can run my in-progress script in the console without ponderously highlighting and ctrl-entering.  I'm then in the console, with everything I just did in memory, and I can go and continue writing my code using the REPL to check how things are working along the way.

In VScode, when I hit the run button

[image]

It just runs the script from the terminal.  I can see any output that it prints, but it doesn't drop me into a REPL interface like I'm accustomed with PyCharm.

Is this sort of functionality attainable with VSCode?

Answer (score 2):

VSCode without this functionality, but it has some similar functionalities:

1. `Ctrl+A` -> rightclick -> `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`.
2. rightclick -> `Run Current File in Interactive Window`

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for exactly the same functionality. Following two other stackoverflow posts you can get the desired behaivor -> executing in an REPL ipython terminal (original links at the end of the post):

edit the terminal launchArgs in settings.json
(Preference: Open Settings JSON; or Preference -> Settings -> Search launchArgs -> edit in json):

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": [
   "-i",       
   "-m",
   "IPython",
   "--no-autoindent",
]
```

Reference Links:

- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310689/use-ipython-repl-in-vs-code)
- [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615414/how-to-set-ipython-jupyter-as-the-default-python-terminal-for-vscode)